# order by absolute values of one column while keeping equal values of another column together in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Example data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(study = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D'),
                 similarity = c(0.61, 0.58, -0.605, 0.4, 0.607, 0.3))

df
   study similarity
1     A      0.610
2     A      0.580
3     B     -0.605
4     C      0.400
5     D      0.607
6     D      0.300
```

I want to order by absolute `similarity`, but keeping equal values of study together. For the above example the result should be:

```
   study similarity
1     A      0.610
2     A      0.580
5     D      0.607
6     D      0.300
3     B     -0.605
4     C      0.400
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(-abs(similarity)), .SD, by = study]
```

**Result:**

```
   study similarity
1:     A      0.610
2:     A      0.580
3:     D      0.607
4:     D      0.300
5:     B     -0.605
6:     C      0.400
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R

```
df[order(-ave(df$similarity,df$study,FUN=function(x) max(abs(x))),df$study),]
  study similarity
1     A      0.610
2     A      0.580
5     D      0.607
6     D      0.300
3     B     -0.605
4     C      0.400
```

Comment: Or `with(df, df[order(-ave(.a <- abs(similarity), study, FUN = max), -.a), ])`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

 df %>%
    group_by(study) %>%  #group by study
    mutate(arr = max(abs(similarity))) %>% #get maximum absolute similarity by group
    ungroup() %>%
    arrange(desc(arr)) %>% #arrange according to by group maximum absolute similarity
    select(-arr) #leave the helper column out
#ouput

# A tibble: 6 x 2
   study similarity
  <fctr>      <dbl>
1      A      0.610
2      A      0.580
3      D      0.607
4      D      0.300
5      B     -0.605
6      C      0.400
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr`. This solution looks more complicated than others, but it aims to generate the expected output even if the `study` column is not in order, or there are ties in `similarity` from different `study` group.

First, Calculate the absolute value of each similarity (`df2`).

Second, Calcualte the maximum absolute of each study (`df3`).

Third,  Covert the study column to a factor column based on the order in `df3`. Arrange the columns based on `study` and absolute value (`df4`)

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% mutate(ABS = abs(similarity))

df3 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(study) %>%
  summarise(Max_ABS = max(ABS)) %>%
  arrange(desc(Max_ABS))

df4 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(study = factor(study, levels = df3$study)) %>%
  arrange(study, desc(ABS)) %>%
  select(-ABS)
df4
#   study similarity
# 1     A      0.610
# 2     A      0.580
# 3     D      0.607
# 4     D      0.300
# 5     B     -0.605
# 6     C      0.400
```